# Why listeners array length is 3 instead of 2 in the last console.log?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, redux

I was writing my own little version of Redux to understand how it works under the hood.

In the code given below, I am wondering why the last console log is not producing expected output.

The comment in the code describes the problem clearly. Help anyone-

```js
function createStore(reducer) {
  let state;

  let listeners = [];
  const getState = () => state;

  const subscribe = listener => {
    listeners.push(listener);
    return () => {
      listeners = listeners.filter(thisListener => thisListener !== listener);
    };
  };

  const getListeners=()=>{
    return listeners
  }

  const dispatch = action => {
    state = reducer(state, action);
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
  };

  return {
    getState,
    subscribe,
    dispatch,
    listeners,
    getListeners
  };
}

// Create the store-
const store = createStore();

// Subscribing to store changes
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("The new state is: ", store.getState());
});

// To check the number of items present in listeners array
console.log("1. store.listeners",store.listeners.length)  // prints length- 1, as expected
console.log("1. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 1, as expected

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("State changes");
});

console.log("2. store.listeners",store.listeners.length) // prints length- 2, as expected
console.log("2. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 2, as expected

const unsubscribe= store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("State changes");
});

console.log("3. store.listeners",store.listeners.length) // prints length- 3 as expected
console.log("3. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 3 as expected

unsubscribe()

console.log("4. store.listeners",store.listeners.length) // printed length- 3 ( Why not 2?)
console.log("4. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 2, as expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listeners.filter` returns new array. But the object you have returned from `createStore` will always have initial reference.

You could use `splice` instead to modify array inplace.

```js
function createStore(reducer) {
  let state;

  let listeners = [];
  const getState = () => state;

  const subscribe = listener => {
    listeners.push(listener);
    return () => {
      listeners.splice(listeners.indexOf(listener), 1);
    };
  };

  const getListeners=()=>{
    return listeners
  }

  const dispatch = action => {
    state = reducer(state, action);
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
  };

  return {
    getState,
    subscribe,
    dispatch,
    listeners,
    getListeners
  };
}

// Create the store-
const store = createStore();

// Subscribing to store changes
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("The new state is: ", store.getState());
});

// To check the number of items present in listeners array
console.log("1. store.listeners",store.listeners.length)  // prints length- 1, as expected
console.log("1. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 1, as expected

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("State changes");
});

console.log("2. store.listeners",store.listeners.length) // prints length- 2, as expected
console.log("2. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 2, as expected

const unsubscribe= store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("State changes");
});

console.log("3. store.listeners",store.listeners.length) // prints length- 3 as expected
console.log("3. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 3 as expected

unsubscribe()

console.log("4. store.listeners",store.listeners.length) // printed length- 3 ( Why not 2?)
console.log("4. store.getListeners",store.getListeners().length) // prints length- 2, as expected
```

Comment: Great. I got is as soon as I read your first line. Thanks a lot, @Yury Tarabanko